# Convert row including another nested row to JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm trying to select the following data structure:

```
week      houses
-----------------------------------
2022-11   [{ ... , "contract": { ... } }]
```

essentially, putting the row from `contracts` table as the sub field "contract" on the houses object.

Just merging the data with:

```
SELECT l.week, jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(h) || to_jsonb(c)) as houses
...
```

works well, but my API needs the contract data to be under the contract sub field.

Where I'm at right now is:

```
SELECT l.week, jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(h) || '{"contract": ' || to_jsonb(c) || '}') as houses
FROM user_listings l
  JOIN houses h ON h.id = l.house_id
  JOIN contracts c on c.house_id = h.id
GROUP BY l.week;
```

But it does not work. I'm getting the following error:

> [22P02] ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json Detail: The input
> string ended unexpectedly. Position: 41 Where: JSON data, line 1:
> {"contract":

I'm out of things to try. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT week
     , jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(sub) - 'week') AS houses
FROM  (     
   SELECT l.week, h.*, c AS contract
   FROM   user_listings l
   JOIN   houses h ON h.id = l.house_id
   JOIN   contracts c on c.house_id = h.id
   ) sub
GROUP  BY week;
```

Assuming there is no column named "week" in table `houses`. Else you have to use a column alias.

See:

- [Select columns inside json_agg](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69658/3684)
- [Postgres multiple columns to json](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/90871/3684)

Comment: This would be much easier to answer with a fiddle to play with ([example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=04b3017aeebd0f1578b6abb135776aa0)). Also more useful to the general public.

Comment: Didn't know dbfiddle existed, thanks.